# How do I join the Minecraft Beta?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, xbox-one

How do I join the Minecraft Beta? I have seen other people using it, but I don't know how to install it on my Xbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To join the Beta in Minecraft Bedrock Edition, you'll have to follow these steps:

1. Download the Xbox Insider Hub app. You can find it easily by searching it up in the store search bar. (The Xbox Insider Hub app is free, and anyone can use it.)
2. Go inside of the app and find the "Join the Minecraft Beta" section. Then, click "Join".
3. Even after you join, you still need to do a few more things. Go to the Home area in your Xbox, and go to "My Games and Apps". Go over to Minecraft, hit the menu button, and click "Uninstall". Don't worry, you won't have to buy it again, and you can install it at any time
4. After you uninstall Minecraft, scroll down to all your games and apps and then install Minecraft again. This will take a few minutes, so be patient.

Once you finish all these steps, open up Minecraft, and look for the "Minecraft Beta" screen. It should be the first thing that comes up. If you don't see that, then you must've done something wrong. Also, here is a picture of the play screen:

[image: Minecraft Beta Screen]

Here are a few more things you might want to do and some things you should be aware of:

- If you want to try out some Minecraft Beta features, you'll want to open up a new world, go to options, and turn on "Caves and Cliffs".
- If you open up any world, you will not be able to play it in the normal Minecraft Bedrock edition, and you can't play with any other people that don't have the beta, so make sure not to open up your favourite worlds unless you don't want to play them with other people!
- When you use the Minecraft Beta, you can't join any servers, or play with other players.

If you want to stop using Minecraft Beta, head over to the Xbox Insider Hub, click the button to stop joining, uninstall and then install Minecraft.

Comment: Minecraft Beta has been (almost) replaced by [Minecraft Preview](https://minecrafthelp.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/4423653831821-Minecraft-Preview-FAQ) now. (Almost because only android still uses the old Beta system).