# Can I access snapshots on PE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Is it possible to play snapshots on Bedrock Edition? If so, how can I? I have looked around the home screen, but I can't find anything related to the snapshots. Is there anything I need to do?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, it is not possible to access snapshots on Minecraft Bedrock Edition. Snapshots are only available for the Java Edition of Minecraft. You *can* however use Minecraft Beta, but that is only available for Android, Xbox, and Windows 10. So, you can't access snapshots or betas on Pocket Edition (unless you are using Android).

Here is a tutorial on how to get it on Xbox One: [How do I join the Minecraft Beta?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/384521/how-do-i-join-the-minecraft-beta/384522#384522)